# How to except the branch in gitlab.ci?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Ran into a problem in gitlab.ci. I have a main branch and a test branch. The remaining branches are release branches and serve as a workspace for developers. What needs to be written in gitlab.ci so that the build-to-dev and deploy-to-dev stages run on all branches except the test branch?

Answer (score 1):

The "[`.gitlab-ci.yml` keyword reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml)" includes a [`only`/`except`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except) keyword which should help.

```
job2:
  script: echo
  except:
    - test
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the [`only/except`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except) Keyword, the [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) keyword can also be used and offers additional functionality than `only/except`.

```
jobs:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == main'
      when: never
  script:
    - echo hello
```

But `only/expect` cant be combined with `rules` on one job